# How does Fulton and Harris establish that the differential of a group hom respects ad?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Fulton and Harris, *Representation Theory*, Section 8.1 (pages 104 - 107 in my copy) is concerned with showing that group homomorphisms $\rho : G \to H$, where $G$ is connected, are completely determined by $(d\rho)_e : T_e G \to T_e H$.  This is used to motivate the definition of a Lie algebra, which comes later on.

They show that $\rho$ being a group homomorphism implies a string of statements.  Up to the statement that

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T_e G @>{d\rho_e}>> T_e H\\
@V{\operatorname{Ad}(g)}VV @VV{\operatorname{Ad}(\rho(g))}V \\
T_e G @>>{d\rho_e}> T_e H
\end{CD}$$

commutes, I'm fully on board.  But then it's claimed that this implies that

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T_e G @>{d\rho_e}>> T_e H\\
@V{\operatorname{ad}(v)}VV @VV{\operatorname{ad}(d\rho_e(v))}V \\
T_e G @>>{d\rho_e}> T_e H
\end{CD}$$

commutes as well, with no explanation given so far as I can see.  How do you get from one to the next?  It seems as though the idea would be to show that every $\operatorname{ad}(v)$ comes from some $\operatorname{Ad}(g)$, but there doesn't seem to be sufficient machinery to do this -- both $\operatorname{Ad}$ and $\operatorname{ad}$ have just been defined on this page!

Comment: Differentiate the first commutative diagram with respect to $g$.

Comment: I got the idea that it was something along those lines, but I'm a bit confused as to what that means.  Do I extend the diagram to something like $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G \times T_e G @>{id \times d\rho_e}>> G \times T_e H\\
@V{\operatorname{Ad}}VV @VV{\operatorname{Ad} \circ (\rho \times id)}V \\
G \times T_e G @>>{id \times d\rho_e}> G \times T_e H
\end{CD}$$
or what?

Comment: You're thinking about this too hard. The commutativity of the diagram says that a certain map between vector spaces, depending smoothly on $g$, is the same as another map between vector spaces, also depending on $g$. Differentiate this identity with respect to $g$.

Comment: The first diagram gives information about the operator $Ad_g$ on a one parameter curve through $e$ such that $Ad_g(x(t))$ is the one parameter curve $g*x(t)*g^-1$ on $G$, where $x(t)$ is a one parameter curve on $G$ passing through $e$. One can show that the action of $Ad_g$ can be generalized to the tangent space at $e$. The second diagram does the same for a one paramenter group $g(t)$ characterized by it's class $v \in T_eG$. Since the first diagram is commutative for all one parameter groups $g(t)$ it is also for its representative $v$.